# Store values from checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following project https://codepen.io/IonutP24/project/editor/ZepjON and the next issue.
I want to select all checkboxes status and store them in variables as :

```
var checkbox1 = checked ? 1 : 0;
var checkbox2 = checked ? 1 : 0;
var checkbox3 = checked ? 1 : 0;
```

After that, i have to compare with the answers from js file and if all are equal, increment 1.

For now i am stuck at storing values from checkboxes in variables.
How can i do that ?

Comment: values or status? which is it?

Comment: `var checkbox1 = $("#myCheckbox").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: I want to store value 1 if is checked, 0 if it's not checked.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. You made my day. Thank you.